# Console output is appearing in email while using jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, automation

I am new to Jenkins and I have integrated my **maven** project with **Jenkins** but when try to send html report through email then a console output is appearing in email. **Already installed notification plugin in Jenkin**s.The scripts which were running is fine but exception occurs while sending email: -

> "Sending e-mails to: example@email.com ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:"

Now, an email is received successfully but in form of console output.
[image: This is the email that I have received output]

Configuration of Post build setup :

[image: Post build configuration]

Using this whole setup in **Ubuntu** system.Please let me know if any other information required.

Comment: My guess is the ```build.getWorkspace().child("test-output/emailable-report.html")``` doesn't exist (wrong directory), or the permissions are incorrect because the first thing in the post build config is reading the report html and since it's saying ```NoSuchFileException```

Comment: The error message comes from archiving `pom.xml`. But you not configure `Attachements` and `Attach Build Log` in email setting.  Did you add any other post action related to `Archive artifacts`?  From the build log the archiving action trigger by Jenkins not by Maven, even so please show your maven pom.xml.